# How to center a label on a custom cell using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom header cell for my tableview, but no matter what constrains i create using the auto layout on xCode, the label always stay a little to the right:

[image: Headers should be centered]

And here is the constrains:

[image: Here are the constrains that should center the label horizontally and vertically in the view.]

[image: Overview]

How can i do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looks like the cell width is wrong. Maybe your table width is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you also constrain your UITableView to your ViewController's boundaries, it looks like the UITableView is wider than the screen.